# Alamofire response contain text before JSON content use it with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm requesting a JSON object with Alamofire and accessing it with SwiftyJSON.

The response of my request is this :

```
// JSON webservice ...
[
    {
        "message":"Please connect"
    }
]
```

As you can see I need to remove the string "// JSON webservice ..." because it is actually not a valid JSON object.
Note that I'm using the .responseString otherwise I could not remove the string part.

So in order to remove the string I'm doing :

```
let jsonString = data?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("// JSON webservice ...", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Now I'm with my String I can do :

```
var json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(jsonString!)
```

and I can print the json :

```
println(json)
```

BUT whatever I print a value

```
println(json[0]["message"].string)
```

is nil.

Comment: What prints when you run `println(json)`?

Comment: @AaronBrager   It prints the response minus the "// ..." part so : [{"message":"Please connect"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found myself a solution :

- We get our string (data) from the .responseString method
- We remove the part that cause the fail of the serialization of the JSON object
- We convert our string to NSData and try to serialize our JSON object :

  ```
  let data = jsonString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray?
  ```
- Now it should be fine and everything is working when trying to print a value of the JSON object

  ```
  var json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(jsonData!)
  println(json[0]["message"])
  ```

It prints the right value.

Comment: That is correct, SwiftyJSON does not accept a JSON string as input, it can only convert already deserialized JSON objects.